# no puedo cambiar el color de la barra de volumen en un reproductor mp3 en python

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

hola amigos de todo corazón espero se encuentren muy bien. como les he comentado en otras ocasiones estoy creando de manera autodidacta un reproductor de audio en python sin embargo surgió un problema y es que no logro cambiar el color de la barra de volumen o cambiarla por una un poco mas bonita, pero hasta donde tengo entendido puedes cambiarle el color (negro en mi caso), al background para que combine un poco mas o entre dentro de el concepto artístico que estas programando(aun cuando use bg=). espero puedan ayudarme y de antemano les agradezco de sobremanera.
les dejo una imagen para que me entiendan mejor (la barra que les indico se encuentra completamente a la derecha.

dejo solamente el código de la barra de volumen y la ventana para no ocupar espacio demás.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import tkinter as tk 
import fnmatch
from tkinter import Frame, Place, Scale, Scrollbar, filedialog
import os
from tkinter.constants import RIGHT, VERTICAL, Y
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from typing import Pattern
import pygame
from pygame import mixer

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Tejon's Bar player")
window.geometry("900x600")
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
window.config(bg='black')

rootpath="C:\\Users\\Victor\\Music\\mi musica"
Pattern="*mp3"

mixer.init()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootpath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, Pattern):
        listBox.insert('end', filename)

volume=ttk.Scale(window, from_=1, to=-0.01 , orient=VERTICAL, cursor='hand2', command=volume, value=1, length=250)
volume.place(x=865, y=40)



window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4):

En los widgets de ttk (como ttk.Scale) rara vez o nunca se puede cambiar un detalle visual sin usar un `style`. No se mucho de styles, pero se lo suficiente como para responder tu pregunta.

Hice un código para pruebas. Es el siguiente:

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk

window = tk.Tk()
window.config(bg='black')

volume=ttk.Scale(window, from_=1, to=-0.01 , orient="vertical", cursor='hand2', value=1, length=250)
volume.place(x=865, y=40)

volume=ttk.Scale(window, from_=1, to=-0.01 , orient="vertical", cursor='hand2', value=1, length=250)
volume.place(x=900, y=40)
```

---

#### Cambiar el fondo de todos los ttk.Scale

Para cambiar el fondo de todos los ttk.Scale, puedes modificar el style utilizado por dicho widget (es decir, el style default):

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk

window = tk.Tk()
window.config(bg='black')

style = ttk.Style()
# El primer argumento es el nombre del estilo
# También notese que uso background para establecer el color, NO bg.
style.configure("Vertical.TScale", background="black")

volume=ttk.Scale(window, from_=1, to=-0.01 , orient="vertical", cursor='hand2', value=1, length=250)
volume.place(x=865, y=40)

volume=ttk.Scale(window, from_=1, to=-0.01 , orient="vertical", cursor='hand2', value=1, length=250)
volume.place(x=900, y=40)
```

Se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como habrás notado, el cambio que hiciste se aplicó a ambos ttk.Scale.

#### Cambiar el fondo de uno de los ttk.Scale

Si quieres puedes darle un style propio a cada ttk.Scale, puedes crear un nuevo estilo derivado del estilo original del widget y asignarle un color de fondo, para luego indicarle al widget que use dicho nuevo style.

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk

window = tk.Tk()
window.config(bg='black')

style = ttk.Style()
# En el primer argumento se coloca un nombre personalizado al style, luego . y luego el style del que se quiere derivar.
style.configure("black.Vertical.TScale", background="black")

# Le paso el argumento style, donde le digo que style voy a usar para este widget. Si este argumento no se pasa, se usa el style default.
volume=ttk.Scale(window, from_=1, to=-0.01 , orient="vertical", cursor='hand2', value=1, length=250, style="black.Vertical.TScale")
volume.place(x=865, y=40)

volume=ttk.Scale(window, from_=1, to=-0.01 , orient="vertical", cursor='hand2', value=1, length=250)
volume.place(x=900, y=40)
```

Queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Más información sobre los styles aquí: https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/ttk-style/

Comment: muchas gracias me respondiste no solo esta duda si no tambien un poco dudas posteriores... lo que si creo es mas complicado es progrmar la progres bar del audio ya que no veo que exista algun comando como para la de volumen o si? igual y este es tema para otra pregunta. Felices fiestas!!